# What is the '100' reaction supposed to mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, reactions

Since a few days ago, our Team has a 'Reactions' feature. They seem to be similar to [GitHub reactions](https://developer.github.com/v3/reactions/), which are canned responses to a post. You can add them by clicking on a smiley. Currently there are four options: 'celebrate', 'help', 'thanks' and '100':

[image: possible reactions]

They're some sort of public (up)vote/comment system, though they do not give reputation. You're able to post reactions on your own posts (not sure if that's intended or an oversight).

Clicking the number below the smiley gives a list of reactions by other users:

[image]

I can think of use cases for 'celebrate', 'help', 'thanks', but what is the '100' supposed to mean? A bounty? Or am I (Dutch native) missing some American office culture thing here?

Comment: oh boy. the future of SO is looking at us...

Comment: What a crappy feature as all things are becoming crappy.  What is this facebook now ?

Comment: SO meets Facebook? oh boy.

Comment: It allows the team member to send you $100. Did you not receive it yet?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm still waiting on $1 which I'm supposed to get from a CM: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322153/295232

Comment: With all these new features, I wonder if we'll soon have a way to share photos of our lives/activities/trips and tag our "friends" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'll do you one better: *why* is the 100 reaction?

Comment: HTTP 100 Continue?

Comment: What is SOS reaction actually for? If you cannot put it on your own question - which would mostly be signal for poor question - putting it on other peoples questions, and especially answers would sound more like stalking.

Comment: It's not celebrate, it's tada. Come on, SO. If you're going to copycat pointless things, at least be accurate.

Comment: @Dalija I think you're mainly supposed to use that reaction on questions pertaining to Message in a Bottle by The Police

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I'll do you one better, [*how*](https://youtu.be/YnB550pA9ts) is the 100 reaction?

Comment: Looks like another ublock rule will be required soon.

Comment: Soon there'll be badges on the number and type of reactions received :/

Comment: @James if they keep the element tags the same a single uBlock rule works to block all of the reactions (I can confirm this works as a collegue had me set it up for his team which hates this)

Comment: The teams literal reaction: "we wanted to use SE to avoid all the Slack level chatting that happens and steals focus from work - why would we want this?"

Comment: @yivi you were right...

Answer (score 31):

I assume it's used in the normal sense of the 100 emoji.

From https://emojipedia.org/hundred-points-symbol/:

> Hundred Points
>
> 100 emoji: the number one-hundred, written in red, underlined twice for emphasis.
>
> Originating from the number 100 written on a school exam or paper to indicate a perfect score of 100 out of 100.  Teachers in Japan may also use a stamp in addition to the 100 mark, to indicate that a student has performed very well.
>
> This 100 emoji is commonly used as a shorthand for 100%, with the usage meaning “keep it real” or a similar sentiment. A 100 emoji can be used to express pride or general acceptance of an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I've never encountered that emoticon in the wild before ... 100 points for this answer!

Comment: My (Android) phone (using [GBoard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin)) annoyingly suggests the 100 emoji every time I type "100". I've never bothered to find out what its meaning was until now.

Comment: scoring centum - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/centum