# Add reputation gained from questions and answers to user profiles

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page

What do you think about the proposal of adding a question/answer reputation summary?

It would be nice to have a way to quickly view the reputation details shown by questions and answers.

Excuse my design skills, but I was thinking an idea like this:

[image]

The green one (which should match the same green as reputation, but I couldn't find it) is assigned to answers and the light blue would show the rep accumulated by questions.

**Update:** to give an example... question rep and answer rep include their respective bounties. For instance, if my question got 10 upvotes and 1 downvote then the question rep would show 98 points (compound of `(10*10)+(1*-2)`), on the case of an answer... if my answer got 10 upvotes, 1 downvote and 50 points of bounty then the answer rep should show 148 points (compound of `(10*10)+(1*-2)+(50)`).

Is this a terrible idea? What do you think?

Comment: What about reputation points associated with downvoting answers and accepted suggested edits?

Comment: @PeterMortensen not sure if I am missing something... the idea is to simply show the reputation that our questions and answers have. If someone downvote my question and my answer, then my rep will show that.

Comment: Side note: I never seen a bounty for a question... seem to be a strange example...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov let's not add noise to the question... you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

What does it buy you?

It may be an interesting side-statistic to see how much of your reputation was gained by questions or answers, but at the end of the day, points are points.

You could also concoct a SEDE query to get this information for you on demand if you ever really wanted it...especially because this design wouldn't be able to take into account:

- bounties
- edits on posts
- accepted answers

...which are more ways of gaining rep not reflected in upvotes.

Comment: The answer to your leading question can be found in your very next sentence. That "points are points" doesn't refute that this is still an interesting statistic. It is at least as edifying as a time-series plot showing reputation gained.

Comment: Why not? It's an interesting data that add value to profile. It is not the same the points gained on questions than rep gained on answers. I find this information a very nice to have.

Comment: @CodyGray:  Is it worth spending dev time on this as opposed to making the profile responsive, or adding other features to the site?  It's an interesting statistic - I agree - but I don't know if I value it higher than other things.

Comment: Let's spend developer time on this, instead of [adding emojis to questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391702/teams-what-is-the-100-reaction-supposed-to-mean). How's that time machine coming along?

Comment: @Makoto, I updated the question but what I ask is something very "simple". If I post a question and it receives 10 upvotes, 1 downvote and a bounty (of 50) then my question rep would show 148 compound of (10*10)+(-2*1)+(50).
Same applies for an answer... if my answer got 10 upvotes and 5 downvotes then my answer rep would should 90 compound of (10*10)+(5*-2)+0 (bounties)

Comment: @CodyGray:  The Teams platform isn't the same as the Stack Overflow platform in that the value add(s) for Teams aren't the same value add(s) for Stack Overflow proper.   If paying customers want emojis on their questions, let 'em pay for them.  For something like Stack Overflow proper (and a larger change to the profile page), is it ***really*** worth the time to do this?